# (simulate) fresh start of the app after some time in the background

Tags: ios

I have an app magazine reader app that downloads list of new magazines from the server. Magazines change once a day. I need to make sure that they are downloaded at least once a day.

I download magazine when app starts, it can take some time so I always show loading screen. Now, the problem is that when app enters the background, it can stay there for long time and I need to download magazines again if it was more than some period of time. I tried to use `applicationWillEnterForeground`, start downloading magazines and show loading screen, but it shows app in the state it was at the moment of exiting while it starts up and loading screen shows after second or two, this looks very weird.

My question is, what should I do to have loading screen visible after app was for some time in the background?
Bet thing would be to kill it after some time period, but I don't think that this possible. Other solution would be to show loading screen before app is resumed from the background, but I don't know how to do that, is it even possible?

Comment: Thought about using the newsstand API? That one will download new issues even when your app is in the background.

Comment: Client does not want to use newsstand (yet)

Comment: If your main issue is the fact that a short "app to background, app to foreground" already triggers your downloader, then why not keeping a timestamp within your app that is created when entering background and compared when reentering the foreground?

Comment: That is not my main issue, I already solved this as you suggested. Problem is that loading displays loading screen, but that loading screen is displayed only after app fully entered foreground, there is last app state displayed during that startup animation and this "screenshot" of the app is what I want to hide, I would like to show loading screen right away, not after app is fully in foreground

Comment: @Lope: have you figured out how to do this yet? I have the same question. thanks!

Comment: @minovksy: sadly, I don't believe it is possible. All I could find was that if change state of app in willResignActive, it will be reflected in that screenshot and on resume it will be updated. This does not help me since I do not know if I will need it at the time when willResignActive is called, but it might be helpful in some other situations

Answer (score 0):

To kill it try:

```
    exit(0);
```

In an app delegate method.... didEnterBackground or Foreground or whatever!

Comment: Surely if you did this it would look like the app crashed.

Comment: and I am sure that apple won't approve this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is a perfect solution, but have you considered disabling the app running in the background?

[image: Application does not run in background]

This isn't suitable for every app and it will increase load time, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I actually want to keep ability for app to run in background, I just need it reset after extended period of time